# Bootstrap 3 push/push columns for small screens only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a bs3 page with 3 columns layout as below:

---

|      1      |             2            |     3      |

---

3 X 6 X 3

on large screens this is fine, however, on small screens(mobile phones), i want the order to be: 2>1>3 like below:

---

|    2       |

---

|    1        |

---

|    3      |

---

what should I use for to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-6">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">3</div>
```

Comment: this helped a lot :) Thanks